# Updating ManyToMany relationship using CriteriaUpdate

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa

I'm trying to update a ManyToMany relationship using CriteriaUpdate.

The following are the entities;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
    
    // Getters and setter...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID")})
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters and setter...
}
```

Below is the code in the DAO

```
void updateCourses(String studentId, Set<Course> courses){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate<Student> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Student.class);
    Root<Student> studentRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(Student.class);
    criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(studentRoot.get("id"), studentId));
    criteriaUpdate.set("courses", courses);
    entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
}
```

The above code throws the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute path for assignment must represent a singular attribute [null.courses]
```

How can I update using CriteriaUpdate?